# Есть ли возможность перевести timedelta в int?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timedelta

Вкратце суть функции вернуть количество дней в конкретном месяце используя модуль `datetime`.
Работает исправно, возвращает `timdelta`

```
import datetime

def days_in_month(year, month):
    year_for1=year
    if month==12:
        month_for1=1
        year_for1=year+1
    else:
        month_for1=month+1
    date1=datetime.date(year_for1,(month_for1),1)
   
    date2=datetime.date(year,month,1)
    
   
    print(date1-date2)

    a=date1-date2
    return a
```

Вторая функция проверяет действительность этой даты, ошибка в `day<days_in_month(year,month)`

Вот что мне вернул Python:

```
File 'datetime.py', Line 363: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

```
def is_valid_date(year, month, day):
    """
    Inputs:
      year  - an integer representing the year
      month - an integer representing the month
      day   - an integer representing the day

    Returns:
      True if year-month-day is a valid date and
      False otherwise
    """
    if (year>=datetime.MINYEAR and year<=datetime.MAXYEAR 
        and month<=12 and month>=1 and day<days_in_month(year,month)):
        return True
    return False


print(is_valid_date(2020,4,1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Количество дней в `timedelta` можно получить через его свойство `days` - значение этого свойства и возвращайте из функции:

```
def days_in_month(year, month):
    ...
    a=date1-date2
    return a.days
```

Тогда сравнение `day < days_in_month(year,month)` будет работать.

Также можно наоборот, переводить день в `timedelta`, но это логичнее делать для сравнения периодов времени, а не для проверки попадания дня в период времени:

```
from datetime import timedelta
print(timedelta(days=10) < timedelta(days=20))
# True, т.е. период в 10 дней меньше периода в 20 дней
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Comment: @Leha, если ответ помог, вы можете поставить галку слева от ответа